# Color change on hover over

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of pictures and when I hover on a picture, I want the rest of pictures turn to black and the one which I'm hovering stays in its original color. would you please help me to do it?

```css
.inst__img {
  width: 11%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inst__img img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<section class="global__inst">
  <div class="inst__img">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35994ab8482c0d6946e0/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="">
    <span>vi</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inst__img">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35994ab8482c0d6946e0/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="">
    <span>vi</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inst__img">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35994ab8482c0d6946e0/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="">
    <span>vi</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inst__img">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35994ab8482c0d6946e0/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="">
    <span>vi</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to select *not hovered* images for grayscale: `img:not(:hover)`

```css
.inst__img {
    width: 11%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.inst__img img{
    width: 100%;
}
.global__inst:hover img:not(:hover) {
    filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); 
}
```

```html
<section class="global__inst">
  <div class="inst__img">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35994ab8482c0d6946e0/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="">
    <span>vi</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inst__img">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35994ab8482c0d6946e0/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="">
    <span>vi</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inst__img">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35994ab8482c0d6946e0/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="">
    <span>vi</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inst__img">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35994ab8482c0d6946e0/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="">
    <span>vi</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Greant answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```css
.inst__img {
  width: 11%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inst__img img {
  width: 100%
}

.global__inst:hover .inst__img img {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.inst__img:hover img {
  filter: none !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="global__inst">
  <div class="inst__img">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35994ab8482c0d6946e0/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="">
    <span>vi</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inst__img">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35994ab8482c0d6946e0/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="">
    <span>vi</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inst__img">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35994ab8482c0d6946e0/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="">
    <span>vi</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inst__img">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35994ab8482c0d6946e0/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="">
    <span>vi</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why don't you post an executable snippet?

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, small typo, fixed my code. But mplungjan answer should be accepted, it's better.

Answer (score 0):

please try the below one. initial all the list images will be black and the hover one can display as you like

```
.inst__img{
  border:2px solid red;
        background: black; opacity:.5
}

.inst__img:hover{
  border:2px solid red;
        background: white;
    opacity:1
}
```